# Creating a loose relationship between multiple objects that others can search on

Tags: java, automated-tests, jbehave

I have a list of car manufacturers, models, and trims. Each of those objects has different attributes on them. Ex. car makers can have import vs domestic, sport vs luxery, etc. My current setup looks something like below,

```
public Manufacturer {
    private String manufacturerName; //Getter&Setter as well
    private List<Model> modelList; //Getter&Setter as well
    //additional attributes
}

public Model {
    private String modelName;
    private List<Trim> trimList; //Getter&Setter as well
    //additional attributes
}

public Trim {
    private String trimType; //Getter&Setter as well
    //additional attributes
}

public ContainerClass {
    public List<Manufacturer> manufacturerList;
}
```

Now I can create the objects as Mazda, 3, Grand Touring and associate the objects in the list. But if someone comes along and just wants a car that has a sunroof, it feels like a waste to have to dig into every possible manufacturer and every model for that manufacturer to see if the trim has a sunroof attribute. Are there any strategies I could use to make this easier for developers, including myself?

Note: I am at a point where I don't have a database because I don't have real data to fill the database, this is a stop gap until I get that data later, so please don't just say "create a database" :). Also I am loading this information from an ExamplesTable object of JBehave.

Comment: Is it better to create big maps (or whatever) and keep the data consistent?

Comment: Side note: naming a class `SomethingClass` or a list `SomethingList` is limiting and not powerful. What if you refactor the list to a set? What does the name tell a maintainer about the _role_ of the thing named? The code already tells us that it's a list or a class or whatever. You just add noise when you name a thing for its implementation. The opportunity is for your names to increase information about the algorithm, and redundant verbiage sacrifices that benefit.

Comment: @ Stefan That is one of the options I have thought about.

Comment: @Lew This is not my real code, it is just an analogy for my real code.

Comment: I would not create such relationships. I would create some stream-filter-code to get it

Comment: @StefanWarminski It's been a while since I have worked with that type of code, could you post an answer with a example of what you mean?

Comment: @swhite all code is real code. Bad habits in practice lead to bad habits in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the manufacturers by some sub-streams:

```
container.getManufacturerList().stream()
    .filter(manufacturer ->
        manufacturer.getModelList().stream().anyMatch(model ->
            model.getTrimList().stream().anyMatch(trim ->
                trim.getTrimType().equals("sunroof"))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This definitely seems like an option for me to use. I'll give it a shot.